# Java BlueCove - Sending information from server to client

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm writing a bluetooth related application, and I'm using a API called BlueCove if you're familiar with it.

I managed to send some text from the client to a server, however I'm not familiar with the API for sending information from a server to a client so I couldn't send any information back to the client. I want to know how to do that.

Could anyone point me to it? I'm really unfamiliar with the API. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be a really simple thing. Bluetooth provides different ways to communicate between devices, and one of them is using `DataStream`. Set up the following on both server and client side, and they'll be able to talk to each other:

```
StreamConnection conn = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
DataOutputStream output= new DataOutputStream(conn.openOutputStream());
DataInputStream  input = new DataInputStream(conn.openInputStream());
```

Whatever is put in DataOutputStream on one end, it'll come out in DataInputStream on the other side of the connection, regardless whether it's a server/client. [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [DataOutputSream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)'s API are found in the link.